# Want to Apply Blur to a Specific Filled Object on Python Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, graphics, blur

I am using Python 3.8.10 on Linux Mint 20.3 Una. I am making a series of animations with a multitude (potentially thousands) of fish shapes, each of which are produced by specifying a 2D profile with points, and is then filled in using the [Pyplot fill function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html).

What I would like to be able to do is to apply a unique blur to each of these individual filled regions based on a computed distance to mimic image depth. An added complication is that these filled regions frequently overlap.

In theory, this could be done by exporting SVG files and manually applying the blurs in Inkscape or some other package, but there are potentially thousands of fish and hundreds of frames, so a way to achieve this in code really is the only realistic way to accomplish it, if it is possible.

Here is the minimal code that produces two filled profiles that I would like to blur individually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

#define profile of object with points

x_profile = [0.5,0.485951301332915,0.423371700761206,0.358237605529776,0.281609306290982,0.23180095266422,0.152618567550257,0.053001860296735,-0.005746611462221,-0.060663545623872,-0.05683323438022,-0.257343937095579,-0.317369329156755,-0.345466399463283,-0.469348762061393,-0.492337251833031,-0.5,-0.439974607938825,-0.418263242861681,-0.415709156986512,-0.461686095651334,-0.492337415346851,-0.483397419850022,-0.466794594429313,-0.363346513092306,-0.342912313588113,-0.31864669912198,-0.289272544999412,-0.236909860226751,-0.210090037250083,-0.183269887245775,-0.146233189348514,-0.078544599457363,0.086206203027589,0.210088361233424,0.310982111424531,0.418261893872663,0.478287408569203,0.493612741389321]
y_profile = [-0.019156461632871,0.002554903444271,0.031928934931474,0.051085805348896,0.065134504015981,0.07024308455087,0.071518492350251,0.067688181106599,0.158365179012477,0.068965632828735,0.049808353626761,0.028096988549618,0.025542085105346,0.03192770857782,0.10217038434414,0.104725287788412,0.091954040843463,0.00255449465972,-0.00255449465972,-0.017879827479838,-0.067688181106599,-0.148148017942698,-0.158365179012477,-0.151979555540003,-0.061302557634125,-0.047254267751592,-0.040868235494567,-0.042143643293948,-0.080457792913345,-0.084288104156997,-0.079179523622108,-0.097059759886497,-0.111108049769031,-0.127710834311284,-0.126435426511903,-0.107278556094481,-0.076627072885143,-0.045975589675805,-0.031927299793271]

#this just makes a second object and offsets it down 0.5 units

n_objects = 2
n_points = len(y_profile)

x_points = np.zeros((n_objects, n_points))
y_points = np.zeros((n_objects, n_points))                  

for i in range(n_objects):
    for j in range(n_points):
        x_points[i,j] = x_profile[j]
        y_points[i,j] = y_profile[j] - i*0.5

#make plot

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches(6.5, 6.5)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor((0,0,1.0))
ax.set_xlim(-1,+1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,+1)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

#create filled regions defined by copies of profile points (I want to be able to apply a blur these fills individually)
          
for i in range(n_objects):
    plt.fill(x_points[i,:], y_points[i,:], color = (0, 0, 0.5))

#tried the following, but does not work at all.

#handle = plt.fill(x_profile, y_profile, color = (0, 0, 0.5))
#blurred = gaussian_filter(handle, sigma=1)

#show plot (normally exporting PNG frames for animation)

plt.show()
```

which should yield this image:

[Fish Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSOyZ.png)

If this is not possible in Python, I'm open to suggestions as to how this could be implemented dynamically in some other way.

I've seen examples of SciPy Gaussian blur applied to regions of static images, but the blur that I want to achieve is specific to the filled "object" which isn't a neat rectangle. I note that when this image is exported as an SVG the individual filled objects appear as distinct entities in that file, but I don't see a way to assign a handle to it within Python and to apply a blur to it. I've tried variations of 'handle = plt.fill(x,y)' and 'gaussian_filter(handle, sigma=1)' but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think i was able to do what you are asking for using convolution but it is not optimized for speed at all. plus, it is kind of hard to tell how well it will translate to your bigger code.

Going off of whay you posted, I converted the graphs to rgb arrays and convolved each dimension separately with a from scratch convolution function (not my own,[1](https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/)). this code will output the first fish image and then a few seconds later it will output the blurred fish image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import plotly.express as px

def Convolve(img, kernel):

    (imgX, imgY) = img.shape[:2]
    (kernelX, kernelY) = kernel.shape[:2]
    #print(imgX,imgY, kernelX,kernelY)
    pad = (kernelX - 1) // 2
    img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, pad, pad, pad, pad, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE) #top, bottom, left, right
    #the above line prevents error with convolution: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (23,22) (23,23)

    output = np.zeros((imgX, imgY), dtype="float32")

    #shift kernel vertical and horizontal across image, pad prevents kernel from going out of bounds
    for y in np.arange(pad, imgY + pad):
        for x in np.arange(pad, imgX + pad):
            #locate specific pixel
            roi = img[y - pad:y + pad + 1, x - pad:x + pad + 1]
            #print(roi)
            #perform convolution
            k = (roi * kernel).sum()
            #populate the result into the previously created np.zeroes array
            output[y - pad, x - pad] = k
    return output


# define profile of object with points

x_profile = [0.5, 0.485951301332915, 0.423371700761206, 0.358237605529776, 0.281609306290982, 0.23180095266422,
             0.152618567550257, 0.053001860296735, -0.005746611462221, -0.060663545623872, -0.05683323438022,
             -0.257343937095579, -0.317369329156755, -0.345466399463283, -0.469348762061393, -0.492337251833031, -0.5,
             -0.439974607938825, -0.418263242861681, -0.415709156986512, -0.461686095651334, -0.492337415346851,
             -0.483397419850022, -0.466794594429313, -0.363346513092306, -0.342912313588113, -0.31864669912198,
             -0.289272544999412, -0.236909860226751, -0.210090037250083, -0.183269887245775, -0.146233189348514,
             -0.078544599457363, 0.086206203027589, 0.210088361233424, 0.310982111424531, 0.418261893872663,
             0.478287408569203, 0.493612741389321]
y_profile = [-0.019156461632871, 0.002554903444271, 0.031928934931474, 0.051085805348896, 0.065134504015981,
             0.07024308455087, 0.071518492350251, 0.067688181106599, 0.158365179012477, 0.068965632828735,
             0.049808353626761, 0.028096988549618, 0.025542085105346, 0.03192770857782, 0.10217038434414,
             0.104725287788412, 0.091954040843463, 0.00255449465972, -0.00255449465972, -0.017879827479838,
             -0.067688181106599, -0.148148017942698, -0.158365179012477, -0.151979555540003, -0.061302557634125,
             -0.047254267751592, -0.040868235494567, -0.042143643293948, -0.080457792913345, -0.084288104156997,
             -0.079179523622108, -0.097059759886497, -0.111108049769031, -0.127710834311284, -0.126435426511903,
             -0.107278556094481, -0.076627072885143, -0.045975589675805, -0.031927299793271]

# make plot

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches(6.5, 6.5)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor((0, 0, 1.0))
ax.set_xlim(-1, +1)
ax.set_ylim(-1, +1)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# create filled region defined by profile points (I want to be able to apply a blur to this)

plt.fill(x_profile, y_profile, color=(0, 0, 0.5))
fig.canvas.draw()

data = np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
array=np.array(data)
R=array[:,:,0]
G=array[:,:,1]
B=array[:,:,2]

fig=px.imshow(array, color_continuous_scale="gray")
fig.show()

_1DKern = cv2.getGaussianKernel(33, 2)  # first value is dimensions, second is sigma
_2DKern = np.outer(_1DKern, _1DKern.transpose())
convR = Convolve(R, _2DKern)
convG=Convolve(G,_2DKern)
convB=Convolve(B,_2DKern)
conv=np.stack([convR,convG,convB],2)

fig = px.imshow(conv, color_continuous_scale="gray")
fig.show()
```

Comment: This does seem to work with a single filled region. But in my workflow I am defining multiple profiles. I've updated my original question code to include a minimal code example of how these additional objects are created and filled.
If I make these changes, your code still works, but it blurs both fill objects. I think the problem is that your code is pulling data from the whole canvas? Is there a way to restrict it to a particular filled object? An added complication is that many of the filled objects may overlap.

Comment: I see the problem. I think this is possible, as i can at least think of an algorithm linguistically, but im not sure how to implement it realistically. This question interests me so I will bounty it when that becomes available (2 days after post), and i will continue thinking about it myself.

Comment: Thanks for exploring this. I wonder if some means of stacking the figures is possible? The overhead might be expensive and I'm not fully familiar with the mechanics beneath the image rendering. I'm reading up on patch polygons and how they can be manipulated.